# Why Event() is not working in controller in laravel?

Tags: jquery, laravel

I couldn't get the `Event()` working inside the controller in laravel.

**In controller**

```
class TimeController extends Controller
{
    public function gettime($divId = null)
    {

     $res = time();
     $even = event(new UpdatedTime($res)); //not working
     return 'Event is updated';
    }
}
```

**Js file**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $.ajaxSetup({
     headers: {
          'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });

  document.querySelectorAll('*').forEach(function(node) {
    var data = '';
    ajax = $.ajax({
      url: '/getTime/' . node,
      method: 'get',
      success: function(data) {
         //parse the server side response
         console.log(data);
         ajax = null;
      }
    });

    //node.innerHTML = ajax.data;

  });
});
// Pusher
    var pusher = new Pusher('xxxxxxxxxxxx', {
        cluster: 'ap3',
        encrypted: true
      });
 
      var channel = pusher.subscribe('updated-time');
   // Binding a function to a Event
     channel.bind('App\Events\UpdatedTime', function(data){
     console.log(data);
 });
```

**Route/web.php**

```
 Route::get('/getTime/{id}', 'App\Http\Controllers\TimeController@getTime');
```

**BladeFile**

```
 <div id="id1">0</div>

 <div id="id2">0</div>

 <div id="id3">0</div>
```

When I Pass this in the  URL `http://project.test/getTime/id1` // It should display the time() for each Div and the Pusher should be updated with the API message, When the event is triggered.

But It not working, Could someone please help?
Thanks

Comment: It would help to add the code for your event.

Comment: Have you registered the Event ?

Comment: @Mahdi , Yes I have registered the Event.

Answer (score 0):

I think Ajax call is failing.

Following change is required:

```
url: '/getTime/' . node
```

To

```
url: '/getTime/' + node.id
```

Comment: After changing the URL, It is not working too.